# What are good examples of using Big Data for a trading strategy?

Tags: data, quant-trading-strategies

As the title say, I am looking for trading strategies in the stock, bond, forex market, that rely on the usage of Big Data. The more out of the box strategy the better. Also if anyone knows any literature survey on the usage of Big Data in finance ... feell free to share.

Answer (score 1):

There have been several publicly available stories on the use of alternative data in investment management, including the use of location data by hedge funds. Here is one pointer: https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2017-12-16/satellites-are-reshaping-how-traders-track-earthly-commodities.